# How to rewrite git history up to a merge commit included

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am trying to rewrite a part of a git repo history using filter-branch.

The history looks like this:

```
branch 1  A---B---E---F---G(HEAD)
                 /
branch 2  C---D-/
```

I am trying to rewrite all the commits starting from `E` included, up to the tip `G`.

So far, I came to the following command:

```sh
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "......" E..HEAD
```

Unfortunately (and according to the doc) this do not rewrite commit `E`.

Using the range `B..HEAD` do not work either as it rewrites all commits from the branch 2.

How am I supposed to rewrite all commits including `E` up to the tip? If that matters, branches 1 and 2 are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [little known revision notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations) that can achieve this:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "......" E^! HEAD
```

`E^!` includes `E`, but excludes all its parents. By specifying `HEAD` as well, you get everything reachable from `HEAD` (and `E`), but excluding everything reachable from the parents of `E`.